# groovy: groovysh interpreterMode preference not working

Tags: groovy, groovysh

I am trying to set `interpreterMode` in groovysh.  I open up `groovysh` and execute `set interpreterMode`, but then when I try to use `def x=1`, `x` does not get set:

```
groovy:000> set interpreterMode
groovy:000> set
Preferences:
    interpreterMode=true
groovy:000> def x=2
===> 2
groovy:000> print x
ERROR groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException:
No such property: x for class: groovysh_evaluate
        at groovysh_evaluate.run (groovysh_evaluate:2)
        ...
groovy:000>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What version of Groovy?

Comment: `Groovy Version: 1.8.6 JVM: 1.8.0_91 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Linux`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`interpreterMode` was added in Groovy 2.4](http://groovy-lang.org/releasenotes/groovy-2.4.html), so while you are correctly setting the preference, the Groovy shell does nothing with it. You can set anything as a preference:

```
groovy:000> set foo
groovy:000> set
Preferences:
    foo=true
```